# If $s+\frac{1}{n}$ is an upper bound for A and $s-\frac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound for $A$ then show $s = \sup A.$

Tags: real-analysis

The question is : Let $A ⊆ R$ be nonempty and bounded above, and let $s+\frac{1}{n}$ is an upper bound for A and $s-\frac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound for $A$ then show $s = \sup A.$

The way I tried to prove this is:

Since $s+\frac{1}{n}$ is an upper bound for all $n \in N$, $s+\frac{1}{n} \geq a$, $ \forall a \in A $. Then using the arcemedian property we know there exists an  $n \in N$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < y$, for $y \in R$. Since it's true for all $n$ we can always choose $n$ in a way such that $\frac{1}{n} < a-b$, $
\forall a,b \in A$. Then we have $s+a-b>a$ $\implies s>b$, $\forall b \in A$. which means that $s$ is an upper bound of the $A$. Now we have a lemma that says : if $s$ is an upper bound of a set $A$ then $s=\sup A$ if and only if for all choice of $\epsilon >0$ there exists an element $a \in A$ such that $s-\epsilon < a$. Since $s-\frac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound for any $n$,  $\exists a \in A $ such that $s-\frac{1}{n} < a$. Now if we choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$, then it follows from the lemma that $s=\sup A$.

Is that the right way to show it?

Comment: What if $b\gt a$? How can we find $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}\lt a-b$?

Comment: @JohnDouma can't we always choose $a$ and $b$ such that $a-b>0$? and since $a-b$ is a real number we know such $n$ exists from the arcemedican property?

Comment: Yes, but the statement that we can always find $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}\lt a-b$ for all $a,b$ is false. If you change the argument to say that $a-b\gt 0$ then you can only conclude that $s$ is greater than those values of $A$ that have another value in $A$ that is greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A\subset\mathbb R$, $A$ has the least upper bound property, is non-empty and bounded above, $A$ has a least upper bound $u$.

Since $s-\frac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound and $s+\frac{1}{5}$ is an upper bound we get that $$s-\frac{1}{n}\le u\le s+\frac{1}{n}\implies -\frac{1}{n}\le u-s\le\frac{1}{n}\implies\lvert u-s\rvert\le\frac{1}{n}$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

If $\lvert u-s\rvert = r\gt 0$ then we could choose $n$ large enough so that $\frac{1}{n}\lt r$ which leads to a contradiction.

Therefore, $\lvert u-s\rvert = 0\implies u=s$